# Web-scraper getting 'Server Busy' HTTP Error 500

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I'm currently trying to login to a website, but with my Python code I just get a 'Due to extremely high usage, the server is unavailable' message (HTTP Error 500).

There's nothing wrong with the server.

Code is:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import urllib.parse

url = 'example.com/login.asp'
values = {'userName': 'username',
          'Password': 'password',
          }
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
try:
    handler = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
    print(e.read())
```

The example.com/login.asp page redirects to the main homepage (example.com), and is  a form within this page. Not sure if that has any relevance.

Comment: Perhaps they've tried to stop your scraper and blocked you? Try connecting from a different IP

Comment: I considered that, but I can log in manually with no problems, from the same IP. I suspect they're blocking the scraper, but not sure what I could do to avoid that?

Comment: Maybe try with a different user agent?

Comment: Tried that as well. Tried Firefox and Chrome. No dice.

Comment: Has this ever worked? My approach would be to use Chrome, log in manually, look at the network tab of your developer console and then see all the request headers. Mirror these in your code - things thing referrer address, etc should all be added to your code as they may (or may not) be significant